# Angular 2- Are there any scenarios where it is advisable to use JiT over AoT

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-template, angular2-aot

From what I understand from the documentation it's advisable to switch to AoT for better load time and even performance post initial load.

If that is the case, then is there any specific scenario where it's preferable to use JiT over AoT.

If not why not expose AoT as the sole and default feature instead of complicating the build with a JiT compiler.

Should I be vary of a scenario where AoT performs worse/fails compared to JIT.

Comment: When you use AOT, your code must be statically analyzable. It might be a problem for example if you decide to create components on the fly. I most cases, you should go for AOT.

Comment: Actually I am using this solution : http://blog.rangle.io/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-2/ in my application to create dynamic components and it's compiling fine with AOT